# Problem after install rospy through conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, ros, rospy

I met a problem when I try to install rospy through conda. First, I use command "`conda activate mujoco_py`" to activate a specific environment I usually use. Then I input the command " conda install -c conda-forge ros-rospy ". Then after I finish installing the rospy, I input the command "`env |grep ROS`", it shows as below:

```
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3.8
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/shine/anaconda3/envs/mujoco_py/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/shine/catkin_final/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/shine/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_IP=192.168.1.7
ROS_ETC_DIR=/home/shine/anaconda3/envs/mujoco_py/etc/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.7:11311/
ROS_ROOT=/home/shine/anaconda3/envs/mujoco_py/share/ros
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
```

My Ubuntu system is ubuntu 20 and install ROS noetic. Does anyone know how to deal with the problem of that? I would like to use ros in my specific conda environment and also without conda it can be also run. I try to use the command "`conda uninstall ros-rospy`" to uninstall it from my conda environment, but I failed.

Comment: My goal is just to use python file through Pycharm compiler to run ROS.  That's the reason why I did that .

Comment: It is unclear what `the problem` is supposed to be. Looks like: 1) you activate a conda env 2) install a package there 3) the package is installed correctly 4) You say you want to solve "the problem"?

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I dealt with the problem with the command "`conda uninstall ros-rospy`" with three times. Sometimes you need to try several times due to the speed of the internet or your personal device situation.